# Can you substitute physical storage with time complexity?

Tags: hash, compression, brute-force

**Inspiration:**

Each proper Sudoku puzzle has only one solution. In the unsolved state, values are omitted. By solving the puzzle, one obtains these values. One can solve the puzzle as intended, or theoretically brute force the solution so that the Sudoku property is held. Could this also be applied to data compression?

**Approach:**

Instead of looking for patterns in the data, can you create a sufficient description with rules that allow only one solution?
Hash functions used for fingerprinting files could be one such rule. But if the data is large, collisions occur in the output of the hash function. Is it possible to construct/find a composition of rules that define a unique solution while being smaller then the original file? If you can find such a rule, you could include the number of bits of the original file and brute-force validate the rule on all permutations of these bits.

Comment: A unique identifier for a 1GB file is in general also 1GB itself

Comment: Your method relies on having access to the uncompressed data when you're decompressing, so is not a compression method as usually understood.

Comment: @PaulHankin What part exactly depends on having access to the uncompressed data?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, but what is "brute force check all possible files"? Ah, perhaps you mean check _all_ possible files of the given size range. But even if this were feasible, there's only 2^1344 files of length 168 bytes, and 2^8589934592 files of length 1GB, so each of the "compressed" files corresponds to roughly 2^8589933248 different files of length 1GB.

Comment: I think your idea is use a 512-byte hash+length as a compressed version of a file. Sorry, but if so that's fundamentally impossible because for large files there isn't enough information to reconstruct the file.

Comment: @PaulHankin Just using the 512-byte hash+length as a compressed version of a file is just an example. I thought like this: If you have a room with 100 people and only one is wearing a blue shirt, you can just say "blue shirt person" and you would know who it is. Now, the length (file size range) would relate to the amout of people in the room and "blue shirt" to the hash value. I know hash functions have collisions, which would the same as there being two people with a blue shirt in the room. So you would need a more detailed search filter, i.e. save the hashs of two different hash functions.

Comment: What you want is provably impossible. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity

Comment: No.............

Comment: By the way, the answer to just the question in the title (ignoring the body) is: Yes, but you're already doing it. Most of the space on your physical storage is occupied by images, audio, and video, all of which are already compressed, and take time to decompress.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not valid. You're not really understanding what lossless data compression *is*.

For any given length *n*, there number of byte sequences that are n-bytes long or less is about 256<sup>n</sup>.

The number of shorter sequences is simply *less*, so no lossless compressor can find a compressed representation for every file.

The goal of a compressor is to assign the shortest possible output sequences to the *most likely* input sequences.  (The relative number of meaningfully shorter sequences is actually very small.)  For every input that it actually compresses, there must be another input that it *expands*.

Any *valid* lossless compressor is therefore based on a statistical model that predicts which inputs are more likely.  You are not making any attempt to model the likelihood of various inputs, so the it's not just the resulting idea that's invalid.  The whole way of thinking about the problem is invalid.

Comment: Well, it should be called a description generator rather than a compressor, but is the direction thinking really wrong? If a program calculates fibonacci(factorial(1000)) and stores the binary representation in a file, the program + the calculation instruction is certainly much smaller than the file. Would a classical algorithm based on a statistical model result in a 22 bytes solution (storing the string "fibonacci(factorial(1000))")? Can you really not "compress" data into a calculation formula and calculation time?

Comment: That name of it doesn't matter.  And yes, you really cannot compress arbitrary data into a formula.  Note that any long data stream that you can define with a short sentence is not "arbitrary"